# NSDatePicker setDate doesn't work as expected

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents, nsdatepicker

I'm trying to set time on a `NSDatePicker` according to a certain offset that I have in milliseconds. When I set the time, the value that I see is off and I can't figure out why.
Here is the code I use to set the picker:

```
- (void)setDatePicker{

    int targetmillisondsFromMidnight = [self.schedule.targetHour intValue]; //Value is: 61680000 milliseconds whis is equal to 17:08 UTC (or 19:08 in my local time);
    NSDate* todayMidnight = [NSCalendar.currentCalendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate new]];
    NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; //Value is: Local Time Zone (Asia/Jerusalem (GMT‎+2‎) offset 7200)
    NSInteger seconds = [timezone secondsFromGMT]; //Value is: 7200
    todayMidnight = [todayMidnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds]; // Value is: 2019-12-25 00:00:00 UTC
    NSDate* scheduleDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:targetmillisondsFromMidnight/1000 sinceDate:todayMidnight]; //Value is: 2019-12-25 17:08:00 UTC

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:scheduleDate];

    [self.datePicker setDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components] animated:YES];
}
```

I stop with a breakpoint at the last command in the function and I print some values, the outputs that I get are:
`po [components hour] = 17`
`po [components minute] = 8`
`po [calendar dateFromComponents:components] = 001-01-01 17:08:00 +0000`

So from my understanding the date is set with 17:08.
What I expect to see on the time picker is 19:08, however what I see is 19:28. I can't figure out where those 20 minutes are coming from.

Comment: `setDate:animated:` is a method of `UIDatePicker`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Date picker uses while setting time current timezone and uses UTC offset based on passed date (001-01-01 17:08:00 +0000) and looks for offset in timezone database at this timepoint. Because at that time (*year zero*) there were no timezones, it could not be found in tz database so time zone offset was calculated based on *mean solar time*, so you got offset `2:20` (approx.) for your area.

```
- (void)setDatePicker {
    int targetmillisondsFromMidnight = 61680000; //Value is: 61680000 milliseconds whis is equal to 17:08 UTC (or 19:08 in my local time);
    NSCalendar *calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
    NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Jerusalem"]; //Value is: Local Time Zone (Asia/Jerusalem (GMT‎+2‎) offset 7200)
    calendar.timeZone = timezone;
    NSDate* todayMidnight = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate new]];

    NSInteger seconds = [timezone secondsFromGMT]; //Value is: 7200
    todayMidnight = [todayMidnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds]; // Value is: 2019-12-25 00:00:00 UTC
    NSDate* scheduleDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:targetmillisondsFromMidnight/1000 sinceDate:todayMidnight]; //Value is: 2019-12-25 17:08:00 UTC

    NSDate *date = [scheduleDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds];

    self.datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    [self.datePicker setDate:date animated:YES];
}
```